# Where to find the sha256sum for Linux Mint 2 "Betsy" - Cinnamon (64-bit)

Tags: linux-mint

I downloaded the Iso for

- Linux Mint 2 "Betsy" - Cinnamon (64-bit)

  from here. https://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=186?id=186
  Then I clicked on the [verify your Iso](https://linuxmint.com/verify.php) link and was taken to this generic page which doesn't give the sha256sum.
  Where is the sha256sum file located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please let me know the mirror link, from where you have downloaded your ISO?

You have to download **sha256sum.txt**  and  **sha256sum.txt.gpg** files first and then you can begin with the different comparison methods for windows as well as in Linux to verify.

It's important to find the shs256sum code first.

**Do it by yourself:**

Let's say for an example your mirror download link is:

http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint//debian/lmde-2-201503-cinnamon-64bit.iso

then you will find your sha256sum file here:

http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/linuxmint//debian/

Once you have the file, you know the rest. Also the above link contains both the files  :) 
Thank you.

Comment: I used the University of Canterbury Mirror

Comment: Thanks. Please click on this link:  http://ucmirror.canterbury.ac.nz/linux/mint/isos//debian/  and download your **sha256sum.txt**  and  **sha256sum.txt.gpg**   file.  If you need help about how to check the sum in Windows or under Mint, then please let me know. Hope this was a help to you. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks. Where does it say that the sha256sum is located there? I wonder why the don't just have it on the download page and save a lot of hassle?

Comment: You're welcome. If you open the **sha256sum.txt** file then you will find a list of **sha256sum** with their appropriate version name and bits(32 or 64). Now you have to generate the **sha256sum** from your downloaded ISO file and then compare it to one that already stated in the  **sha256sum.txt** file. If they match then everything is good.  This link: https://linuxmint.com/verify.php explains all. You're right about that they should mention it on the download page. I heard that they are planning to it. So you will definitely get it in the near future. Let me know if anything. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer was any help to you, then please upvote my answer and close the topic so that others who have similar type of issues can found this answer helpful. Thanks again.